# Find a power series representation (centered at x = 0) and determine the radius and interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

For the following function:

$f(x) = (x/(2-x))^3$

How do I find a power series representation (centered at x = 0) and determine the radius and interval of convergence?

I managed to simplify the function to 
$f(x) = -(1-(2/x))^-3$ but I have no idea where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Outline: Our function can be rewritten as
$$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{2^3}\cdot \frac{1}{(1-x/2)^3}.$$
To find the expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-t)^3}$, note that for suitable $t$ we have
$$\frac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots.$$
Differentiate twice with respect to $t$.